# get the selected value from sql result populated dropdown list in php html

Tags: php, html

I have populated dropdown list from the `sql` result in `php` and now i am trying to get the selected value to a `php` variable in the same page , but it is not working. Can you help. Below is the code.

```
<?php
     $mid="mario";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prdy" ;
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     echo "<select name='list'>";
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['col_of_fac'] . "'>" . $row['col_of_fac'] . "
     </option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
     $varsel = $_POST['list'];
     echo "hai";
     echo $varsel;

 ?>
```

`$varsel = $_POST['list'];` is not working.

Comment: please add your form so we can help you better

Comment: please post your select name in insert query ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should

1- use a form

2- send the variables with method "POST" to the same file php

```
 <?php
     // display the errors
     error_reporting(E_ALL);
     ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>

 <?php
     // when the form submitted
     if(!empty($_POST['list'])){
       echo $_POST['list'];
     }
 ?>

 <?php
     // connection test
     $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db"); //replace the (user, pass, db) with your parameters
     if (mysqli_connect_errno())
     {
       echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
       die();
     }

     //if your connection succeded
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prdy" ;
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
 ?>

 <form method="post" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <select name="list">
    <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
      <option value="<?= $row['col_of_fac']; ?>"><?= $row['col_of_fac']; ?></option>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="valider">
 </form>
```

if you want to print the value selected and not without form

then you have to use jquery

```
 <?php
      // display the errors
      error_reporting(E_ALL);
      ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  ?>

  <?php
      // when the form submitted
      if(!empty($_POST['list'])){
        echo $_POST['list'];
      }
  ?>

  <?php
      // connection test
      $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","db"); //replace the (user, pass, db) with your parameters
      if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        die();
      }

      //if your connection succeded
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prdy" ;
      $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  ?>

  <select name="list">
     <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)): ?>
       <option value="<?= $row['col_of_fac']; ?>"><?= $row['col_of_fac']; ?></option>
     <?php endwhile; ?>
   </select>

   <p id="value-selected"></p>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
       $(function(){
           $("select[name=list]").on("change", function () {
                 var valueSelected = $(this).val();
                 $("#value-selected").html(valueSelected);
           });
       });
  </script>
```

Comment: @djac; what do you have as result ?

Comment: "hai" and value of $varsel is not getting displayed. I think even the if condition itself not working. FYI- dropdown list is populated.

Comment: @djac can you please explain..what you are looking for exactly?

Comment: @bfahmi, it is not working, the selected value is not getting displayed.By the way, why  do we need <input type="submit" value="valider"> ?

Comment: @djac; you have to click the submit input to receive the $_POST; after you select the value, click the submit and what do you have as result ?

Comment: @bfahmi, yes clicked , but value is not displayed.  and fyi, my intention is to get the value when something is selected in dropdown list(as explained in original question), not by button click

Comment: @djac; if you want to have the value with change selected in the same page and without form, then you are not in the correct path, because you have to use jquery and not php ($_POST)

Answer (score 0):

$varsel = $_POST['list']; is not working. : it will work only when the form is submitted by the post method ,

(with current code select box is printed and you are fetching post without submitting the form)
The logic should be like 
In Form Select box is made using your below code and user select and click on submit:

```
 <?php
     $mid="mario";
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_prdy" ;
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
     echo "<select name='list'>";
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     echo "<option value='" . $row['col_of_fac'] . "'>" . $row['col_of_fac'] . "
     </option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
 ?>
```

2. After form submitted below code should execute and in Network console , in page headers you can see if the required data is transferred to the requested page